# Maven + OSGi bundle build complication

Tags: maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm currently developing an OSGi based application (using Felix). In this project, there are bundles depending on other bundles. In the past we were using Ant script to compile and build everything, and now we want to mavenize this, however the task is not trivial at all.

Here is the folder structure I have:

```
+-shared
 -- pom.xml 
 -- someProject
  --- pom.xml
 -- org.apache.felix
  --- pom.xml
 -- org.apache.activemq
  --- pom.xml
 -- org.apache.log4j
  --- pom.xml
 -- org.snake.yaml
  --- pom.xml
 -- ...
```

Obviously, the root POM is supposed to build everything here, and the individual POMs simply describe the bundles. I also have `MANIFEST.MF` files in each bundle (not auto-generated). I must say that we don't want to get the stuff from the common repository, but rather to have our own local one.

Right now, I am **not** using any plugin like [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) and I am trying to do this myself. However I get a lot of errors, which are mostly `package does not exist` errors. Therefore I suspect I am doing something wrong. After looking around in the forum, I noticed that a lot of people have been using the [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html), so I also started to consider to do so. However, the official website could help me only until a certain point, then I got stuck.

So long story short, I'd like to have a functional `pom.xml` which can at least compile. It may also generate the `MANIFEST.MF` automatically, would be nice, however, I am not sure how should I proceed.

So far I came up with this `pom.xml` (of `someProject1`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>shared</groupId>
      <artifactId>shared.master</artifactId>
      <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>shared</groupId>
   <artifactId>shared.cmd.felix</artifactId>
   <name>shared.cmd.felix</name>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>shared</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.apache.felix</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../org.apache.felix/felix.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>shared</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.apache.log4j</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../org.apache.log4j/log4j-1.2.17.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>${jdk.version}</source>
               <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <archive>
                  <manifest>
                     <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                     <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                     <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                  </manifest>
                  <manifestEntries>
                     <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                     <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                     <Bundle-ClassPath>.</Bundle-ClassPath>
                     <Export-Package>shared.cmd.felix</Export-Package>
                  </manifestEntries>
               </archive>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

and `pom.xml` of `org.apache.felix`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>shared</groupId>
      <artifactId>shared.master</artifactId>
      <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>shared</groupId>
   <artifactId>org.apache.felix</artifactId>
   <name>org.apache.felix</name>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
</project>
```

and the `MANIFEST.MF` I have is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Shared Felix Console Extension
Bundle-SymbolicName: shared.cmd.felix
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Fragment-Host: shared.mw;bundle-version="1.0.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 bundle/system/org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime-0.10.0.jar
Export-Package: shared.cmd.ext
Import-Package: shared,
 shared.cmd,
 shared.comp,
 shared.mw,
 shared.sched,
 shared.service,
 org.apache.felix.service.command,
 org.apache.log4j,
 org.osgi.framework
Require-Bundle: org.apache.felix;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 org.apache.activemq
```

however, I get errors like:

```
[ERROR] /shared/shared.cmd.felix/src/shared/cmd/ext/ListScheduledTasks.java:[11,40] package org.apache.felix.service.command does not exist
[ERROR] /shared/shared.cmd.felix/src/shared/cmd/ext/ListScheduledTasks.java:[15,19] cannot find symbol
```

Now, if I want to change this to a state which can utilize [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html), how could it be? I came up with this, but don't know if this corresponds to the one I have above:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>shared</groupId>
  <artifactId>shared.cmd.felix</artifactId>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>shared.cmd.felix</name>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.felix</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.log4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Export-Package>--WHAT TO PUT HERE?--</Export-Package>
            <Private-Package>--WHAT TO PUT HERE?-</Private-Package>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Activator>--WHAT TO PUT HERE?-</Bundle-Activator>
            <Export-Service>--WHAT TO PUT HERE?-</Export-Service>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and more importantly, do I need to insert everything there? Can't I skip some of those, such as `Export-Service`? And what happened to the local paths that I was entering above, why doesn't the plugin have these? Does it automatically find them or?

Could someone help me out with this? I would appreciate any contribution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're beginning it might be be better to start with (which is visible in your setup) then you could learn a lot of the basics in OSGi from the http://enroute.osgi.org site. After you mastered the basics it will be quite easy to setup a maven project if then then still want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to do all the package imports and exports by hand. Even if you achieve it the code will be very brittle as you would have to adapt to all refactorings. If you then also want to do the package uses clauses by hand you are totally screwed.

I have used the maven-bundle-plugin as well as the bnd-maven-plugin. Both work great. If you project is designed well then you will not need much config at all.

The [tasklist-ds example](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist-ds) shows how to apply this to a complete tree of bundles.

I configure the [maven-bundle-plugin only in the parent pom](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/tasklist-ds/pom.xml#L107-L118). The actual config is done in [bnd.bnd](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/tasklist-ds/model/bnd.bnd) files that are imported.

You can start by keeping them empty. Then look at the bundles that are generated. You can then tune the imports and export but try to keep those special configs to a minimum.

Comment: I just saw that you used Bundle-ClassPath. Only do this if you really need to embed something into your bundle. Normally it is not needed.

Comment: So your suggestion is to utilize the project given in that Github account, come up with a .bnd file and pass it as an argument in the pom.xml, did I get it right?

Comment: Also, how did you know what goes into that .bnd file? Like, why is `org.hibernate.proxy` imported, but `org.apache.aries.jpa` is not, and so on?

Comment: Normally you do not need to add special imports. The bnd lib figures it out from your code. org.hibernate.proxy is a special case as hibernate enhances the classes at runtime. So this dependency is not known at compile time.

Comment: Seems a bit complicated for the first-timer. However, from what I understood, I have to use the `bnd-maven-plugin` with a `bnd.bnd` file to get this built. I don't know though what to do put here, like the dependencies, which is the main problem. In my own pom.xml as well this was the problem. I include `org.apache.felix`, and it still tells me that `org.apache.felix.service.command` is not found. I have no clue how to figure out what should be a dependency, and what should not.

Comment: Can you create an example showing your problem in a github repo? I can then look into it and give some more specific answer. I have written some gogo commands and never needed to define any special imports. Have you tried to simply keep the bnd.bnd file empty?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `bnd-maven-plugin`, you **don't add dependencies at all** in your `bnd.bnd` file. You only add them in `pom.xml` in the standard Maven way. Follow any standard Maven tutorial for this.

If you are getting errors from the Java compiler about unknown packages, then it just means you have missed a build dependency in pom.xml.

Given your starting point I think it would be easiest to begin building your project as a plain Java project... don't worry about OSGi at all yet! This will make sure that you have all the compile-time dependencies you need, and again you can use any standard Maven tutorial if you get stuck.

Once you have a plain Java project that actually builds, then you can add in the `bnd-maven-plugin` in order to turn your JARs into bundles.

Full disclosure: I am the original author of the `bnd-maven-plugin`.